# Dynamic Wordpress archives Year/Month/Post excerpts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, archive

I have a wordpress website on which I'm trying to build a dynamic archive page. What I am trying to achieve is something that will be structured like this:

Years

Months

Thumbnail+Title+Excerpt+Date+Comments count

Something like this : http://www.garancedore.fr/archives/ (thumbnail view only)

As of now, all I managed to do is using the Smart Archives Reloaded plugin. Unfortunately my poor knowledge of programming only allowed me to make it look like that :

http://www.imghack.se/121815

As you can see It doesn't highlight the most recent year but the most ancient one and all I have is my post titles.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, whether It's editing the smart archives plugin or having alternatives solutions.

Thank you

Comment: Tell me what happened when you clicked on this link yourself http://imagik.fr/uploads/48475 - You did test it before adding it, right?

Comment: I did yes and I can see my image. I'll upload it elsewhere.

Comment: When I clicked on that link, it prompted me to save as...

Comment: I changed it. Do you see it now ?

Comment: Yes I can see it now.